# Java applet Displaying Text in window center at Start and following when mouse moves

Tags: java, applet, mousemotionlistener

I am trying to write a program that displays a String on start and then once the mouse moves into the window it follows it around and then stops once mouse exits window. I am able to get the String to follow the mouse but cannot seem to get it to display center at program start and follow mouse. I tried using update but that just drew several String's at once. Any guidance is appreciated.

Here is my code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import javax.awt.event.*;

public class Follow_Me extends Applet implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{
        int x;
        int y;
        String text;

   public void init(){
       // Add Mouse Listeners
       addMouseListener(this);
       addMouseMotionListener(this);

   }

   public void paint(Graphics g){
     /* This is where I want to display the String
        and then allow it to move wherever the mouse moves 
        once inside window. 

        g.drawString("Hello", 230, 150);

        but once I set it to the center, my mouseMoved
        will not do anything. It will only move with
        text if the coordinates are set within method.

     */

     g.drawString("Hello", x,y);
   }

   // Unused mouse listeners
   public void mouseReleased (MouseEvent e){}
   public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent e){} 
   public void mouseDragged (MouseEvent e){}
   public void mousePressed (MouseEvent e){}
   public void mouseEntered (MouseEvent e){}
   public void mouseExited (MouseEvent e){}

   // Used mouse motion listener
   public void mouseMoved (MouseEvent e){
        x = e.getX();
        y = e.getY();
        text = "Hello";
        repaint();
   }
```

Comment: In your init method, set the x/y value...

Comment: @MadProgrammer thank you. Did not even think that would be the solution. This is probably off topic, but how do I help limit these types of errors? I read the Java docs and reference guide and textbook I have. Is it just the need to practice?

Comment: Trial and error really, try something, see if it works..